# Compiling nettle 3.2 for arm gnueabi

Tags: linux

First I'll say have little Linux experience.

But I have got this far, i've been trying to update my netgear stora NAS MS2110, it does not support tls1.2 so I set about manually compiling what's needed to update WGET, which needs openssl, gnutls and their dependencies compiling, its my understanding I have no access to a package installer with any updates to those libs/tools.

I've successfully compiled a few things, but in order to continue I need to compile nettle3.2 but it always fails with an assembler error:

> Bad instruction 'rrx, rr'.

I've spent ages searching for tips etc but cannot find any help, I've spent a good weeks on and off on this project and don't want to give up.

Here is the version info.

```
bash-3.2# uname -a
Linux axentraserver.xxx.mystora.com 2.6.22.18-Netgear #16 Sun Jun 13 19:54:46 EDT 2010 
armv5tejl armv5tejl armv5tejl GNU/Linux

bash-3.2# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.22.18-Netgear (mostafah@es5x86.axentra.com
) (gcc version 4.2.1) #16 Sun Jun 13 19:54:46 EDT 2010
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the name and version of your 'Linux OS' .

Comment: Hi its using hipserv and the        bash-3.2# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.22.18-Netgear (mostafah@es5x86.axentra.com
) (gcc version 4.2.1) #16 Sun Jun 13 19:54:46 EDT 2010

Comment: bash-3.2# uname -a
Linux axentraserver.xxxxxxxxxxx.mystora.com 2.6.22.18-Net
gear #16 Sun Jun 13 19:54:46 EDT 2010 armv5tejl armv5tejl ar
mv5tejl GNU/Linux